# Don't understand why my for loop code isn't working

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I was playing with the break and continue keyword but I notice in chrome console this code doesn't work

```
     for (let i = 0; i > 5; i++) {
     console.log(i);
     } //this will print all number from 1 to 5 but console showing undefined
```

However I tried changing i = 5 or i === 5 still it doesn't work

But when I changed it to i < 5 then it yields correct result.

Why is that?

Comment: `let i = 0` OK, so `i` is zero. `i > 5` is zero greater than five? No. That's also the answer to "should the loop be executed".

Answer (score 2):

your condition is i > 5. At the beginning i = 0 so it will not run ever.
put i < 5

Answer (score 1):

Please check following diagram

[image: diagram]

Condition getting false on the first time so code block won't execute

Answer (score 0):

`i<5` indicates that the for loop will run as long as `i` is less than 5. `i>5` indicates that 0 is less than 5 (`let i = 0`). So the correct program should be -

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
     console.log(i);
}
```